# Script error: can't get folder in Applescript?

Tags: applescript

I am trying to search a folder of multiple images and move the images that have _master in the file name to a different folder. Below is what I have achieved but I keep on getting the error

> cant get folder

```
tell application "Finder"
    set the_files to get every file of folder "Mac HD:Users:anthonypassler:Desktop:skincare:"
end tell

tell application "Finder"


   repeat with this_file in the_files

       if name of this_file ends with "master.png" then

           move file this_file to folder "Mac HD:Users:anthonypassler:Desktop:skincare:Test"

       end if

   end repeat

end tell

end
```

Comment: tell application "Finder"
 set the_files to get every file of folder "Mac HD:Users:anthonypassler:Desktop:skincare:"
end tell


tell application "Finder"
 
 repeat with this_file in the_files
  
  if name of this_file ends with "master.png" then
   
   move file this_file to folder "Mac HD:Users:anthonypassler:Desktop:skincare:Test"
   
  end if
  
 end repeat
 
end tell

end

Answer (score 0):

> cant get folder

means the path is not valid, it's maybe misspellt.

Since the desktop folder of the current user is the *root* folder of the Finder there is a shorter form:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set the_files to files of folder "skincare"

    repeat with this_file in the_files
        if name of this_file ends with "master.png" then
            move this_file to folder "Test" of folder "skincare"
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

However there is a second mistake: You have to remove the `file` keyword in the *move* line as `this_file` is already a file specifier.

Comment: How would one use a path to the file instead of the root folder on my desktop? Because the folder is actually on a server

Comment: `folder "NameOfVolume:Path:To:file.ext"`